# How to do sql subtraction

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to do the following with similar syntax?

```
select count(*) FROM main_iteminstance where item_type_id='TITLE'
-
select count(*) FROM main_catalog
```

In other words `count1` *minus* `count2`.

Comment: `Select ( first select ) - (second one); ` is enough. Also you can use `case` reserved word, search about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't try it, but you could do it by using subquery as below:

```
select (query1.cnt-query2.cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt from ...) as query1, (select count(*) as cnt from ...) as query2
```